# Find an hidden permutation of a string C++

Tags: c++, string, permutation

I have two strings, and wanted to check if the second is a permutation of the first (and viceversa of course).
So I found out on cplusplus reference that the ***is_permutation*** function of the library ***algorithm*** could help me. Indeed, I have the following code:

```
int main () {
   string s1 = "bear";
   string s2 = "reab";
   if ( is_permutation (s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin()) )
        cout << "Found permutation.\n";
   else cout << "No permutations found.\n";
   return 0;
}
```

And this works. But now, for example, let's say I still have the string "bear", and a second ***random*** string that inside has a permutation of bear, so something like this:

```
s1 = "bear";
s2 = "AsdVYTcKIyqbNQreabJUoBn";
```

As you can see there's still the permutation "reab". How can I actually check if there's an hidden permutation? And eventually, save it on a "s3" different string?

Hope you can help me.

Comment: You can check all four (s1. length) char consecutive substrings and use the is_permutation on each substting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `std::string::substr` and `is_permutation` to achieve this.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using std::string;
using std::cout;

int main () {
    string s1 = "bear";   
    string s2 = "AsdVYTcKIyqbNQJUoBnreab";
    size_t i;
    for( i = 0; i <= s2.size() - s1.size(); i++)
    {
        string s3 =  s2.substr(i, s1.size());
        if ( is_permutation (s1.begin(), s1.end(), s3.begin()))
        {
            cout << "Found permutation.\n";
            break;
        }
        else 
        {
            continue;            
        }          
    }
    if(i > s2.size() - s1.size())
        cout << "No permutations found.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

See live demo [here](http://cpp.sh/5py4z).

Comment: You are welcome :) I made a slight change to the code to include the corner case when the permutation appears at the end of the string as well.

Answer (score 0):

as kingW3 already pointed out in the comments on how one might do it.

```
string s1 = "bear";
string s2 = "AsdVYTcKIyqbNQreabJUoBn";
string key = "";

for (int i = 0; i < s2.length()+1 - s1.length(); i++)
{
    key = s2.substr(i, s1.length());
    if (is_permutation(s1.begin(), s1.end(), key.begin()))
        cout << "Found permutation.\n";
    else cout << "No permutations found.\n";
}
return 0;
```

*Edit*: Please note that the for loop condition has to be writtenm with either +1 or -1 in order to get the last character from your second string.

```
    i < s2.length()+1 - s1.length()
```

or

```
    i < s2.length() - (s1.length()-1)
```

hope it helps.